# MySQL Query optimize for performance

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, sap-commerce-cloud

Could you please optimize this query for me:

```
SELECT
  case when EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      usergroups item_t1
    WHERE
      (item_t0.p_b2bunits = item_t1.p_uid)
      AND (item_t1.TypePkString = 8796095217746)
  ) THEN true ELSE false END as active,
  item_t0.p_b2bunits as code,
  item_t0.p_accountname as name1,
  item_t0.p_accountnameextension as name2,
  case when EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      user2salreprelation item_t2
    WHERE
      (
        item_t2.SourcePK = item_t0.PK
        and item_t2.TargetPK = 8828959653892
      )
      AND (item_t2.TypePkString = 8796150399058)
  ) THEN true ELSE false END as isFav
FROM
  account2salesrep item_t0
WHERE
  (
    item_t0.p_showondashboard = 1
    AND item_t0.p_district = '4'
    AND (
      LOWER(item_t0.p_accountname) LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT('crampel alu', '%'))
      OR LOWER(item_t0.p_accountnameextension) LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT('crampel alu', '%'))
      OR LOWER(item_t0.p_b2bunits) LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT('crampel alu', '%'))
    )
  )
  AND (item_t0.TypePkString = 8796149842002)
order by
  item_t0.p_accountname
LIMIT
  0, 11;
```

Comment: It is hard to debug with only query given. We need to see explain plan, table description. If possible please add data example and expected result all in text format, maybe query can be written in another more efficient way

Comment: Do you really need to `CONCAT` what appears to be static strings?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. And, you should know that `LIKE '%something'` with a leading `%` is almost impossible to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

**Typing**  If `TypePkString` is a VARCHAR, then you must quote `8796150399058`, else performance will be really bad.  (The opposite situation does not matter.)

**true/false** A boolean expression (such as `EXISTS(...)`) return `0` for false and `1` true, so this

```
CASE WHEN (...) THEN true ELSE false AS ...
```

can be simplified

```
(...) AS ...
```

Some of these **indexes** may help:

```
item_t0:  INDEX(p_showondashboard, p_district, TypePkString, p_accountname)
item_t1:  INDEX(p_uid, TypePkString)
item_t2:  INDEX(SourcePK, TargetPK, TypePkString)
```

**Unnecessary LOWER** Assuming that `p_accountname` has a collation ending in `_ci` [Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`], you can remove `LOWER()` as being unnecessary and slow.

**LIKE** with a leading wildcard (`%`) defies indexing.  Have you considered using **FULLTEXT** (if the users enter "words", not random strings).  It would involve

```
FULLTEXT(p_accountname, p_accountnameextension, p_accountnameextension)

MATCH(p_accountname, p_accountnameextension, p_accountnameextension)
      AGAINST('+crampel alu' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Is `crampel alu` a column name?  A prefix?  Something else?